# Apache : You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, apache2

[EDIT : SOLVED] It was a parent folder permissions issue
I have the well known issue "You don't have permission to access / on this server" with Apache on Ubuntu 14.04. I've already looked for answers in stackoverflow but the answers I found was to allow symbolic links, indexes and add "allow from all" in my conf file, permissions I've already had. Thanks for your help.

I have this error in my /var/log/apache/erro.log :

```
[core:error] [pid 524] [client 127.0.0.1:60607] AH00037: 
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/stm
```

I made a symbolic link in my folder /var/www/ to my workspace :

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 camilo camilo   46 juin   1 11:25 
stm -> /home/camilo/web/stm.fr//
```

when i make a ls -l command in my symbolic folder /var/www/stm, i have this :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 camilo camilo 4096 juin   1 12:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 camilo camilo 4096 juin   1 10:49 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 camilo camilo  850 juin   1 10:04 authentification.php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 camilo camilo  692 juin   1 09:29 connexion.php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 camilo camilo   34 mai   31 17:09 index.php*
```

My stm.conf file allow the directory and to follow links :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@stm.fr
    ServerName stm.fr
    ServerAlias www.stm.fr

    DocumentRoot /var/www/stm
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/stm>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So what's wrong or missing ?

Comment: What are the file permissions for `/home/camilo`, `/home/camilo/web` and `/home/camilo/web/stm.fr` ? Most likely one of those locations is not accessible to the http server process.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 2 camilo camilo 4096 juin   1 12:31 ./``drwxr-xr-x 4 camilo``camilo 4096 juin   1 10:49 ../`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 camilo camilo  850 juin   1 10:04 authentification.php*`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 camilo camilo  692 juin   1 09:29 connexion.php*`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 camilo camilo   34 mai   31 17:09 index.php*`

Comment: And the other two folders I mentioned?

Comment: ok thanks  the parent folder "web" had 700 permissions , I put 755 permissions, thanks for your help !